# 2dsphere index of mongodb fails on this polygon

Tags: mongodb, geojson, 2dsphere

having already lots of polygons in my collection, but on this one the creation is not possible.. anybody have an idea why?

http://geojsonlint.com/ says this polygon is okay... :(

> { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "Mistelbach" },
>   "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [
>   16.404454018255159, 48.74046143931465 ], [ 16.40433758938687, 48.740577868182939 ], [ 16.404454018255159, 48.74046143931465 ], [ 16.427856220781329, 48.762233637684766 ], [ 16.434958381746984, 48.765610074865158 ], [ 16.460456303902362, 48.809038042737107 ], [ 16.518670738047067, 48.798210157986198 ], [ 16.533922919792982, 48.810668046893163 ], [ 16.593301642620577, 48.782841547371994 ], [ 16.663741107935671, 48.780978685479361 ], [ 16.6777125721304, 48.766541505811475 ], [ 16.682486155730267, 48.727770692671101 ], [ 16.724051261709587, 48.738132861948856 ], [ 16.760609926352458, 48.716942807920184 ], [ 16.800312170439149, 48.705882065432689 ], [ 16.869470918203056, 48.712402082056897 ], [ 16.879483800875946, 48.723346395676103 ], [ 16.901954572455804, 48.718107096603077 ], [ 16.918021756279739, 48.699594906545066 ], [ 16.911036024182376, 48.680151285540731 ], [ 16.925007488377105, 48.672001264760475 ], [ 16.924425344035658, 48.638819037297992 ], [ 16.904166720953302, 48.640798328058914 ], [ 16.906611727187379, 48.625662575181288 ], [ 16.859574464398456, 48.634278311434706 ], [ 16.847349433228068, 48.623916142156951 ], [ 16.857013029296091, 48.609595391357352 ], [ 16.811372912926643, 48.615649692508399 ], [ 16.797052162127045, 48.628689725756814 ], [ 16.783895700010341, 48.631716876332341 ], [ 16.779704260751924, 48.635209742381022 ], [ 16.733947715514184, 48.627758294810498 ], [ 16.727427698889979, 48.614718261562082 ], [ 16.736043435143394, 48.609711820225641 ], [ 16.725914123602216, 48.605986096440382 ], [ 16.678178287603558, 48.630552587649447 ], [ 16.677363285525534, 48.629504727834842 ], [ 16.698553339554206, 48.612156826459717 ], [ 16.702744778812622, 48.587124619777498 ], [ 16.679924720627898, 48.56139383988554 ], [ 16.702279063339464, 48.530074474315683 ], [ 16.675267565896323, 48.525417319584108 ], [ 16.664439681145407, 48.522506597876877 ], [ 16.631723169156086, 48.48967365701926 ], [ 16.657221091311463, 48.480825063029265 ], [ 16.637195325965685, 48.465107165810196 ], [ 16.613327407966356, 48.47465433300993 ], [ 16.606458104737282, 48.465107165810196 ], [ 16.5457986643585, 48.465107165810196 ], [ 16.544285089070737, 48.461381442024937 ], [ 16.558023695528888, 48.429363503245348 ], [ 16.58107661145019, 48.420165622650487 ], [ 16.569666582357829, 48.416672756601798 ], [ 16.596445222064393, 48.390709118973263 ], [ 16.596328793196104, 48.390476261236685 ], [ 16.597725939615575, 48.379997663090634 ], [ 16.641736051828975, 48.354965456408415 ], [ 16.635798179546214, 48.344952573735526 ], [ 16.660830386228437, 48.338316128243029 ], [ 16.602965238688601, 48.314681067980281 ], [ 16.571180157645593, 48.326091097072641 ], [ 16.549058672670604, 48.33191254048711 ], [ 16.526005756749299, 48.328536103306718 ], [ 16.512034292554571, 48.334473975589475 ], [ 16.498761401569578, 48.34250756750145 ], [ 16.463599883346177, 48.348561868652496 ], [ 16.44310840252724, 48.355198314144992 ], [ 16.441245540634611, 48.368238347393408 ], [ 16.416213333952388, 48.379415518749191 ], [ 16.426808360966724, 48.399906999568124 ], [ 16.421336204157122, 48.408755593558119 ], [ 16.435424097220139, 48.406776302797198 ], [ 16.445436979893028, 48.4243570619089 ], [ 16.432629804381193, 48.429712789850214 ], [ 16.445669837629609, 48.433438513635473 ], [ 16.43926624987369, 48.441821392152313 ], [ 16.410275461669627, 48.437513524025604 ], [ 16.407830455435551, 48.449156410854549 ], [ 16.40759759769897, 48.449389268591126 ], [ 16.434841952878692, 48.476284337165978 ], [ 16.438567676663954, 48.499453681955572 ], [ 16.427274076439883, 48.503761550082281 ], [ 16.427972649649618, 48.512260857467403 ], [ 16.427390505308171, 48.512843001808854 ], [ 16.403406158440553, 48.51167871312596 ], [ 16.396303997474899, 48.513541575018593 ], [ 16.415165474137783, 48.53088947639371 ], [ 16.415049045269495, 48.532286622813182 ], [ 16.415049045269495, 48.532635909418055 ], [ 16.365333918509915, 48.549983810793172 ], [ 16.394906851055428, 48.574433873133948 ], [ 16.377442520812014, 48.574433873133948 ], [ 16.355204606968737, 48.59841822000157 ], [ 16.339719567486245, 48.597370360186964 ], [ 16.340418140695984, 48.576878879368024 ], [ 16.31701593816981, 48.593178920928544 ], [ 16.312242354569946, 48.590384628089602 ], [ 16.308167344179818, 48.567797427641452 ], [ 16.2896551541218, 48.566050994617115 ], [ 16.286977290151142, 48.570009576138951 ], [ 16.287675863360882, 48.590151770353017 ], [ 16.301880185292188, 48.594226780743149 ], [ 16.300599467741005, 48.608780389279325 ], [ 16.268581528961416, 48.602726088128279 ], [ 16.253212918347216, 48.641264043532068 ], [ 16.262294370073789, 48.643592620897856 ], [ 16.257753644210503, 48.65465336338535 ], [ 16.20140207195843, 48.648133346761149 ], [ 16.199189923460931, 48.656632654146271 ], [ 16.199539210065797, 48.661988382087586 ], [ 16.215606393889736, 48.690047739345331 ], [ 16.210483523685003, 48.701574197305987 ], [ 16.225619276562625, 48.705649207696112 ], [ 16.215955680494606, 48.735804284583068 ], [ 16.223639985801707, 48.740112152709777 ], [ 16.272656539351548, 48.741276441392671 ], [ 16.329939542549937, 48.731263558719782 ], [ 16.34286314693006, 48.74558430951938 ], [ 16.359745332832023, 48.728003550407678 ], [ 16.404454018255159, 48.74046143931465 ] ] ] } }

Comment: anybody can give me a tip?

Comment: What error do you exactly get when trying to post that?

Answer (score 1):

am I right in thinking it is in fact a MultiPolygon when it has 3 brackets around the coordinates? Specs here for brackets: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4

Is your index setup on 'geometry'? What error are you getting? Another gotcha can be when the first and last point do not match in polygon.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think u are right, but its also not working with 2 brackets. other polygons are also stored with 3 brackets.. strange. i also checked start and endpoint -> its the same. i am inserting this polygon using PHPmongoDB .. no error occurs, but its also not in the collection :(

Comment: i just tryed inserting with mongoshell and got the error:  Duplicate vertices: 0 and 2

Comment: thanks that was it... [ 16.404454018255159, 48.74046143931465 ] exists two time.. in position 0 and in position 2

Comment: haha cool, please give me an upvote if it helped :) ahh strange how that passes geojsonlint if that was the issue!

Comment: i wont answer my own question :-).. please write it down and i give u the points